# How to fix laravel 5.5 dusk chromedriver 2.3 error with Chrome 64?

Tags: php, laravel-5.5, laravel-dusk

- PHPUnit 6.5.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors
- MacOS High Sierra 10.13
- Laravel 5.5
- Laravel Dusk
- Chromedriver 2.35.528157
- Chrome browser 64.0.3282.119

> Error: 
>  1) Tests\Browser\ExampleTest::testBasicExample
>   Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownServerException: unknown error:
>   unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Cannot navigate
>   to invalid URL"}   (Session info: headless chrome=64.0.3282.119)
>   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528157
>   (4429ca2590d6988c0745c24c8858745aaaec01ef),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.2
>   x86_64)

I have tried this solution:

```
 return RemoteWebDriver::create(
            'http://localhost:8000', DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(
                ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options
            )
);
```

then the next

> error was: 
>  1) Tests\Browser\ExampleTest::testBasicExample
>   TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities::__construct() must be
>   of the type array, null given, called in
>   /private/var/root/Documents/blvnp/phpunit_testing/PPP/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php
>   on line 127

There are others who have the same problems. There also questions about this in stackoverflow, but those were long ago, my question is different because I am using the latest versions.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments([
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--headless'
    ]);

    return RemoteWebDriver::create(
        'http://localhost:8000', DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(
            ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options
        )
    );
```

Comment: yes, that was the one that I tried but failed. I also put APP_URL= http://localhost:8000